# Date to String object conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have use the following code snippet to convert the Date object to string .

```
 var startDate = new Date();
 var result = Globalize.parseDate(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

but it will return the null value. How to convert the Date object to string specific format ?

Comment: MomentJS is your best friend when it comes to JS and date manipulation. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: you have to do it by breaking day, month and year from date.

Answer (score 4):

To know all possible ways, check **[this link](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)** out.

I've put all the  **[DEMOS here...](http://jsfiddle.net/dQK23/)**

### STANDARD JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months start with zero
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
</script>
```

### MOMENT.JS:

**[Download here...](http://momentjs.com/)**

```
<script>    
    var a = moment([2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
    a.format("MM/DD/YYYY,");    
</script>
```

Don't want to download, simply add this line:

```
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

### jQuery UI:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

### IE:

```
var d1=new Date();
d1.toString('MM-dd-yyyy');
```

### Globalize:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var result = Globalize.format(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using **[Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)**.

What you should do is to format the date, not parse it.

```
var startDate = new Date();
var result = Globalize.format(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
var startDate = new Date();
alert((startDate .getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate .getDate() + '/' +  startDate .getFullYear());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8mPH/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

**Reference:** [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

MomentJS has a very robust set of time formatting options, you can use them.

Below is the example how it will work in your case

```
moment(stateDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a date object as a parameter and returns a string in `MM/DD/YYYY` format :

```
function format(date) {
    return [
        ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
        date.getFullYear()
    ].join('/')
}
```

Usage example (gives today's date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format) :

```
format(new Date) // "01/03/2014"
```

You can easily change the resulting format with a few modifications :

```
function format(date) {
    return [
        date.getDate(),
        date.getMonth() + 1,
        ('' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-2)
    ].join('-')
}
```

Usage example (gives today's date in `D-M-YY` format) :

```
format(new Date) // "3-1-14"
```

---

### Playing around

I've tuned the function a bit, this might be interesting for very basic needs :)

```
function format(date, format) {
    var i = 0, bit;
    if (!format) format = 'MM/DD/YYYY'; // default
    format = format.split(/([^DMY]+)/i);
    while (bit = format[i]) {
        switch (bit.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
            case 'D': format[i] = date.getDate(); break;
            case 'M': format[i] = date.getMonth() + 1; break;
            case 'Y': format[i] = date.getFullYear(); break;
        }
        if (bit.length === 2) {
            format[i] = ('0' + format[i]).slice(-2);
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    return format.join('');
}
```

Usage examples :

```
format(new Date)             // "01/03/2014" (default)
format(new Date, 'd/m/y')    // "3/1/2014"
format(new Date, 'D/M/Y')    // "3/1/2014"
format(new Date, 'DD-MM-YY') // "03-01-14"
format(new Date, 'M/YY')     // "1/14"
```