# parse date in javascript - date format is variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to parse a date format in javascript, however the date format is variable.

I have the dateformat in a variable:

```
function getLocaleDateString(locale) {

var formats = {
    "ar-SA": "dd/MM/yy",
    "bg-BG": "dd.M.yyyy",
    "ca-ES": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "zh-TW": "yyyy/M/d",
     ....
return formats[locale]
}

var dateformat = getLocaleDateString(locale);
```

so for example I may have a date string dd/mm/yyyy 30/01/2015 or it may be mm/dd/yyyy 01/30/2015

I need to parse this to a date object in javascript.. But as I'm unsure of the format, I don't know how I can parse it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse/2587398#2587398

Comment: Ive seen that, but its no good because it requires u programming in the date format... for example Date.parse("1/1/1970") will only work for mm/dd/yyyy  and the other one requies u knowing the date format while programming

Comment: Regardless of how you intend to parse the string, you **must** know the format and tell the parser as it is impossible to reliably determine the format from a string unless it is one of the unambiguos formats (e.g. ISO 8601).

Comment: `30/01/2015` and `01/30/2015` this can be easily detected and can be parsed..  What about dates like `03/01/2015` and `01/03/2015`?  Do you think it is easy to detect without knowing the date format?

Comment: I will have the dateforamt in a string ie "dd-mm-yyyy" and the date ie "01-06-2014' I just need to convert to date object

Comment: What I need, is a library, that has a function DateParse(datestring, dateformat)

Comment: Why not just code a function to do this yourself? Format the dates so they are all manageable (replace all 0# with just #) then handle the specific cases.

Comment: Blind help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20898946/1636522.

Comment: you can use `date.js` `parseExact` https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact it supports array of formats too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write it by hand you'll need a library. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

Given `I will have the dateforamt in a string ie "dd-mm-yyyy"` you can easily parse the string using a function like:

```
function parseString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(s[2], --s[1], s[0],0,0,0,0);
}

console.log(parseString('04-03-2014')); // Tuesday, 4 March 2014
```

Comment: Another down–voter without the courage to explain their convictions. Perhaps they were annoyed over a comment or other answer and, unable to defend their position, vent their spleen by randomly down–voting an unrelated answer. Or maybe they have a valid point, I'll never know. I'm baffled as to why "*use library X*" is a better answer (or at least, less deserving of a down vote), perhaps the downovter thinks all questions should be answered like that. I agree that that isn't defendable, hence no comment.